# PHP - Combine 2 arrays where key is the same multiple times

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I have 2 arrays that i wish to combine, however the values in both arrays are the same but i still wish to combine them. Is this possible?

Lets say i have the following arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => 2683 [1] => 2683 [2] => 2683 [3] => 2683 [4] => 2683 [5] => 2683)

Array ( [0] => 2097152 [1] => 4194304 [2] => 6291456 [3] => 8391910 [4] => 234889216 [5] => 234889280)
```

I used array_combine but then it only displays 1 value. In this case i want they key to allow duplicates, or atleast bring them somehow together in an array where i can simply loop through them.

Is this possible with arrays? Or does anyone else have a better solution? I have to later loop through them and have the matched values, thats the point. 
Below my code if that helps.

```
try {
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT deviceid, interfaceoid FROM poorten WHERE deviceid = '2683'");
      $stmt->execute();

      $deviceid = array();
      $interfaceoid = array();

      if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
          //echo "" . $row['deviceid'] . " : ";
          //echo "" . $row['interfaceoid'] . "</br>";

          $deviceid[]     = $row['deviceid'];
          $interfaceoid[] = $row['interfaceoid'];
        }

        $result = array_combine($deviceid, $interfaceoid);
        var_dump($result);
      }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Something went wrong: " . $e->getMessage() . "";
    }
```

Comment: I think you should use array_push.

Comment: @Zooly, thats not what i want. This will just bring them together, which is not what i want. There is a difference between array 1 and array 2.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `deviceid` as an array key:

```
$result = [];
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        if (!isset($result[$row['deviceid']])) {
            $result[$row['deviceid']] = [];
        }

        $result[$row['deviceid']][] = $row['interfaceoid'];
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats what i was looking for, i'm still quite new to developing and didn't know how to do it. I have 1 more question though, if you don't mind, how can i foreach loop through this? Maybe this seems like a stupid question, but your code is a little hard for me to understand at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for [**live demo**](https://eval.in/786976) and **[live demo](https://eval.in/786977)**

```
foreach($values as $k => $v)
{
    $result[$keys[$k]][] = $v;
}
$result = array_map(function($v){return count($v) > 1 ? $v : $v[0];}, $result);
```